# Conditional Expectation: Arrival Time of First Person

Tags: probability-theory

> A party is being held from 8pm to midnight on a certain night, and $N\sim Pois(\lambda)$ people are going to show up. They will all arrive at uniformly random times while the party is going on, independently of each other and of $N$.
>
> Find the expected time at which the first person arrives, given that at least one person shows up.

I'm having trouble reconciling my answer with a simulation. I think my simulation is fine, but I can't seem to find the error in my derivation? My attempt:

Let $T = \min\{U_1,\ldots, U_N\}$ be the first arrival time, where the $U_i$ are iid Unif(0,1). Then $T|N=n \sim Beta(1,n)$ and
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(T|N\geq 1) 
&=& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{E(T | N=n) P(N=n)} \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n+1} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}} \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}} \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} \left(e^\lambda - 1 - \lambda \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

```
λ = 2
pois = Poisson(λ)
t = []

ntrials = 1_000_000

for trial in 1:ntrials
    N = rand(pois)              # sample of size 1 from poisson(λ)

    if N >= 1
        arrivaltimes = rand(N)  # sample of size N from uniform(0,1)

        push!(t, minimum(arrivaltimes))
    end
end

println(mean(t))
# 0.3429771461235064

println((x -> exp(-x)/x * (exp(x) - 1 - x))(λ))
# 0.296997075145081

histogram(t, normed=true)
```

[image: hist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace $P(N=n)$ with $P(N=n \mid N \ge 1)$.
If you fix this you will get your original answer, divided by $P(N\ge 1) = 1-e^{-\lambda}$, i.e.
$$\frac{e^\lambda-1-\lambda}{\lambda e^\lambda(1-e^{-\lambda})}.$$